# Graphtoolkit mock provider error in react library

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

> I am using the toolkit components to create a library using(create-react-library), and the main app which use library also has some toolkit components, when ever i link the library to the main app there is problem with the same : "error Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider". The library and the main app work independently they render the graph toolkit components , there is a problem when I do npm link and link to main app Or publish and install the library

Answer (score 1):

This is a common toolkit error when incompatible mgt packages are used, and is why "same" name registry error occurs.

In your modules or package.json, I assume you are using React,  and therefore a common dependency tree is:

```
"dependencies": {
 "@microsoft/mgt-element": "*",
 "@microsoft/mgt-react": "*",
 "@microsoft/mgt-msal-provider": "*",
}
```

This should **not** include the @microsoft/mgt package as well. See the Npm site for more examples https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt-react or samples included in the package itself:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/tree/main/samples/react-app

Comment: Hi Nic Vogt- i tried the above solution with in the main app package.  - 
{ "@microsoft/mgt-element": "*",
   "@microsoft/mgt-react": "*"}  and the library we created to be used in the main app has - 
{      "@microsoft/mgt-element": "*",
        "@microsoft/mgt-react": "*"}

when i try to import the library in the main app this is what i get 
×
NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "mgt-mock-provider" has already been used with this registry

Comment: @UmamaheshwariG Can you provide us a sample or some more information on the mgt repository, https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/new/choose
There must be another collision in your setup somewhere.

Comment: here is the link for the information. 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/1496